# How to destroy a specific widget at once ? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

When i pressed the "Create New" button a submit button will be appear at the bottom. But whenever i choose the drop down value the submit button will be destroyed and a new button called "Update" will be shown. But the problem is that, when I repeatedly choose the drop down value and go back to "Create New" button, the "update" button can only be destroy once. Is it a way to find all the update button and destroy all at once ? Thanks

**When i pressed create new button :**

[image]

**When i choose a few times of drop down list value and go back to "create new", the submit and update button is stacked together  :**

[image]

**Code:**

```
def submit():
    deleteAllEntry()
    global CreateJsonBtn, profilenameLbl, ProfileNameEntry
    CreateJsonBtn = Button(jsonframe, text="Submit", command=submit, width=11)
    CreateJsonBtn.place(x=370, y=540)
    CreateNewJsonBtn.configure(state=DISABLED)

    UpdateJsonBtn.destroy()

#Get value inside the dropdown value
def dropdown(choice):
    if (jsonprofileName == ""):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "Fail to retrieve value. Try again later", icon="error")
    else:
        cursor = con.cursor()

        cursor.execute("select * from json where jsonprofilename='" +options.get() + "'")

        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        deleteAllEntry()
    global row
    for row in rows:
        insertAllEntry()

    cursor.close()

    try:
    #Delete submit button when select existing value
        CreateJsonBtn.destroy()
        CreateNewJsonBtn.configure(state=NORMAL)
    except:
        pass

    finally:
        global UpdateJsonBtn
        UpdateJsonBtn = Button(jsonframe, text="Update", command=submit, width=11)
        UpdateJsonBtn.place(x=370, y=550)
```

Comment: Why don't you just change the label's name from "Submit" to "Update" and back to "Submit"?

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for your response.  But changing the label name doesn't fix the issues i guess. Because different button hold different operation.

Comment: @Johnnyyy You can configure the command as well `button.config(text='update',command=update)`

Comment: @AST do you have any links for me to research about this topic  or can you come out with a sample code? Thanks

Comment: @Johnnyyy Look at [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111195611/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method). Using that you can change both the text and command of the button using 1 `.config` call like what AST suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of destroying and creating buttons multiple times, you can configure them, check the example below

```py
from tkinter import *

def foo():
    print('called foo')
    button.configure(text='bar',command=bar)

def bar():
    print('called bar')
    button.configure(text='foo',command=foo)

root=Tk()

button=Button(root,text='foo',command=foo)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`config`/`configure` is a universal widget method, you can use [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) refernece to learn more about them.

The reason you are currently facing the issue is that every time the dropdown is used, a new button "Update" is placed on top of the previous one (if one already exists). The `UpdateJsonBtn` holds the last assigned instance and hence deletes the topmost one, if there are buttons underlying, they will not be destroyed. I would not suggest the approach currently used by you.

In the question you stated if there is a way to get all the buttons that say "Update", you can do that using the following (again, I am not suggesting to use this in your case, but just to answer your question)

```py
for widget in jsonframe.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(widget,Button):
        if widget['text']=='Update':
            widget.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Yes i know my approach is kinda stupid. Although the .config method worked, but it doesnt go in the way i want. For example, i need to add another delete button whenever the drop down list is selected. So in this case, the problem will still occurred because of the drop down list `command`

Comment: You can declare all the buttons separately (initially), if you don't need them at the very instance you can use `place_forget` and hide them from view, later when you need them call `place` on it with the required parameters (you don't need to create a new button every time)

Comment: Ohh yaa thanks for the guidance. Will probably try with this way.

Answer (score 0):

So I know that it should work with `CreateJsonBtn.place_forget()`

You can try that

Comment: I tried with this but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Any errors or something? Also are you sure the hide is getting called in the function (Maybe build in some Debug output to test that)?

Comment: @FlexGames The issue is not with `place_forget` or its execution, the op had multiple buttons stacked over one another, using this or `destroy` would only remove/delete the last assigned instance, the ones below still remain.